# Showing $\{x\in \mathbb{R}:\mu(\{x\})>0\}$ is a countable set under certain conditions.

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\mu$ be a measure such that $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{R}}, \mu)$ is a $\sigma$-finite measure space. I have to prove that $D=\{x\in \mathbb{R}:\mu(\{x\})>0\}$ is a countable set.

Let us suppose that $D$ is not countable, and let $\mathbb{R}=\displaystyle\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}X_{n}$, with $\mu(X_{n})<\infty$ for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Then there exists $n_{0}\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $X_{n_{0}}\cap D$ is not countable. I want to show that this implies $\mu(X_{n_{0}})=\infty$, so we would have get a contradiction. I do not know how to do it. If there is any other way, please, let me know.

Comment: Let $F=X_{n_0}\cap D$. Let $F_m=\{ x\in F\mid\mu(\{x\})\ge1/m\}$. At least one $F_m$ contains infinitely many elements. What does this imply about the measure of $F$?

Comment: Let $m_{0}\geq 1$ such that $F_{m_{0}}$ contains infinitely many elements. Then $\mu(F)\geq \mu{F_{m_{0}}}=\infty$, isn't it?

Comment: Sorry; I assumed $F$ was measurable, but now I don't see why this should be so. However, you would have a subset of $X_{n_0}$ with infinite measure, which can't happen, since $\mu(X_{n_0})<\infty$.